# SHR with only one operand

Tags: assembly, x86

I am working on some `32-bit x86` assembly code analysis projects. Right now I am really confused with the following instruction:

```
shr %edx
```

I understand the semantics of opcode `shr`, and as far as I can see, this opcode needs two operands. So, could anyone give me some guide on the meaning of the above instruction? Is it equal to the following instruction (in AT&T syntax)?

```
shr $2, %edx
```

Comment: The single operand version of [_SHR_](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html) is using an implied immediate of 1. `shr %edx` shifts _EDX_ one bit to the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As any opcode reference will tell you, `SHR` with only one operation implies that you are shifting only one bit.

You may want to either find an [online](http://ref.x86asm.net) instruction reference or grab a PDF copy of the [Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-manual.html) instruction references.